# How to install/update to repo nVidia driver 304.88-0ubuntu0.0.2 after installing nVidia's Proprietary driver from their website?

Tags: nvidia

I installed nVidia driver 310.40 from nVidia's website on my 12.04 laptop. Now thier is an update in update manager showing there is a new version of nvidia driver in the repo 304.88-0ubuntu0.0.2. If I wanted to update back to this older version of the repo driver can I just do it over the top of the nvidia proprietary driver? Do I need to uninstall, purge or do anything else before changing back to the repo driver?

If I didn't want to install the repo driver how I can stop it from appearing in the update manager everyday?

Thanks for you help,

Greg

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you, just wondering if you had an issues with rolling up to 310.4. I just had a nightmare of rolling back to 304.88 cause lightdm / x failed repeatedly with 310.4. I'd have PMed, but I don't think stack has that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed driver version Nvidia 304.88-0ubuntu0.0.1.  Everything works pretty well, except that now Steam is putting out a message stating that nvidia 304.88-0ubuntu0.0.2 needs to be installed.  That's what I'm about to do.

In order to install the drivers, I follow this page's instructions:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/02/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-manually-in-ubuntu/

It worked well for me for the driver version I have now, and that's what I'm about to do for the next version.